# Split retrieved artifacts in two separate lib directories

Tags: ivy

In my web application, there are two separate lib directories:

- `/lib`, and
- `/web/webroot/WEB-INF/lib`.

The idea behind it is that libraries in the latter one are used by front-end code only, and the first one by *both* the front-end and the business logic code. There is a class loader in place which lets the business logic code *not* see the jars in /web/webroot/WEB-INF/lib.

**How can I tell ivy that certain dependencies should go to the second directory while all others go to first one?**

It's not trival since the the web class loader can see jars in both directories and I don't want jars to be in both directories.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Configurations are used to create logical groupings of dependencies:

**ivy.xml**

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.myspotontheweb" module="demo"/>
    <configurations>
        <conf name="frontEnd" description="Jars used by front end"/>
        <conf name="businessLogic" description="Jars used for business logic"/>
    </configurations>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="commons-lang"    name="commons-lang"    rev="2.5"   conf="businessLogic->default"/>
        <dependency org="commons-codec"   name="commons-codec"   rev="1.4"   conf="businessLogic->default"/>
        <dependency org="commons-cli"     name="commons-cli"     rev="1.2"   conf="frontEnd->default"/>
        <dependency org="commons-logging" name="commons-logging" rev="1.1.1" conf="frontEnd->default"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

The ivy *retrieve* ant task can use these configurations to populate your directories:

**build.xml**

```
<target name="init" description="--> retrieve dependencies with ivy">
    <ivy:retrieve conf="businessLogic" pattern="lib/[artifact].[ext]"/>
    <ivy:retrieve conf="frontEnd" pattern="web/webroot/WEB-INF/lib/[artifact].[ext]"/>
</target>
```

**Example**

```
$ find . -type f
./build.xml
./ivy.xml
./lib/commons-lang.jar
./lib/commons-codec.jar
./web/webroot/WEB-INF/lib/commons-cli.jar
./web/webroot/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging.jar
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `businessLogic->default` and `frontEnd-default` in the ivy.xml file?

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582419/what-does-the-little-arrow-do-in-the-ivy-dependency-section/13597757#13597757 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417304/ivy-what-is-the-master-configuration-and-why-is-it-not-pulling-jvyaml/11420292#11420292