# what does the little arrow -> do in the ivy dependency section?

Tags: ivy

i'm using ivy and the firm i work at has a few fun little ivy and ant tutorials.

Each tutorial helpfully *completely* skirts around what the arrow does in an ivy build xml file, when used in the dependencies section.

So, given this setup:

```
<configurations>
      <conf name = "runtime" />
      <conf name = "build-tests" extends="runtime" />
   </configurations>
   ...
   <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency org="blah" name="junit" rev="default" conf="build-tests->runtime"/>
        <dependency org="blahblah" name="xmlutil" rev="default" conf="build-tests->testing"/>
        <dependency org="blahblahblah" name="slf4j" rev="default" conf="build-tests->simple"/>
    </dependencies>
```

What is each dependency declaring? I thought that build-tests was already extending runtime (from the config declaration), so why does the dependencies conf restate this? Is is needed?

The `testing` and `simple` aren't declared in the ivy.xml i have, are they magic and exist outside a formal declaration?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configuration mappings are designed to associate locally declared configurations to configurations declared in a remote module.

```
   mylocalconf->remotemoduleconf
```

What are configurations? They are logical groupings of files, typically used to populate classpaths or directories.

"simple" and "testing" are not part of the [standard configurations generated for remote maven modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104364/how-are-maven-scopes-mapped-to-ivy-configurations-by-ivy/7116577#7116577), suggesting that you're downloading from an ivy repo? Check the ivy files of the dependencies, you'll find the missing configurations there.